# Java equivalent of Ada Select statement

Tags: java, multithreading, ada

Does anyone know if it's possible to have an Ada-style select statement for threads in Java or if there is an equivalent way to do it?

Specifically I would like to be able to use structures:

```
select
  javaThread.someEntry();
else
  //do something else if call not accepted straight away
end select
```

or

```
select
  javaThread.someEntry();
or
  //delay before entry call expires
end select
```

Where `someEntry()` is a synchronized method that could take a bit of time to enter due to a lot of other threads wanting the lock as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, there are a number of ways of accomplishing this.  One way is to use any of the [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) objects which has a `tryLock(...)` method which allows you to wait for the lock for a certain amount of time.  It returns `true` if it was able to acquire the lock or `false` if it timed out.  [`ReentrantLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) may be a good choice here.

```
private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
...

if (lock.tryLock(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
   try {
      // we were able to lock
   } finally {
      // always unlock in a finally
      lock.unlock();
   }
} else {
   // trying to lock timed out without locking
}
```

After some discussion in comments, I now understand that you have existing `synchronized` methods that you'd like to wait for only for a certain amount of time.  Unfortunately, there is no way to do this in Java with the `synchronized` keyword.

Comment: Very nice! Is this compatible with synchronized methods, do you know? In other words I guess, is it possible to use the lock word on a class object in tryLock? Or would the class have to extend Lock?

Comment: No it doesn't work that way.  `synchronized` methods are not compatible with `Lock` objects.  You could wrap your methods in `lock.lock; try { // method stuff } finally { lock.unlock(); }`.  Extending `Lock` would _not_ work.

Comment: I suppose if you extended lock or had a public lock you'd have to make sure that each class that wants to call would implement the tryLock, finally, else thing properly.

Comment: Yeah, it would be ugly.  The whole point of synchronizing is not to hold the lock for too long.  If you are doing this then maybe you should be reading more about concurrency in Java @dakotapearl: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: Absolutely. I think I miss-worded my question in that regard though. The problem is more that I have a pre-written class with synchronized methods that are going to be used by a lot of threads, not necessarily for a long time, and the wait time because of that might be quite high. I was thinking that it would be nice if my thread could get on with something else in the mean time and come back later to try again. Sorry about that. (corrected question)

Comment: Hrm.  Unfortunately, there is no way to do a `synchronized` that times out  @dakotapearl.

Comment: Hmm oh well. I really like the locks, but I might have to leave this one open to see if anyone has something else to add. Thanks for your input, Grey. I appreciate it!